# How to edit huge amount of records and pics in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have an old table with thousands of posts. Each post have 0-4 link to pictures, about a product. Now I have to use the data in the old table to crate a new, and to move the pictures into different folders. I also have to create thumbnails for every picture.

This task sound me a big job, with a long runtime. Should I write the code for this only in a single .php file, than just let the server to run it, or there is a special technique for this. All in all how can you work with huge tables and tons of pics via php?

Comment: Why are you doing this with php? Is the result something a user will see?

Comment: Aside from creating thumbnails, wouldn't it be easier to do this directly in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out how can I solve it so I share the technique I used.

I wrote a code in PHP that manipulates the database, moves the pictures and creates thumbnails for each post (row in the table). Because of the big amount of posts, I wasn't able to run this correctly because the `max_execution_time` was set to `30` and of course the runtime was much bigger, so I divided the task to 30 sec parts. I added a new column (where I store if a row has processed) to the table, and always only selected the rows that weren't processed before. After all, I created a cron job that runs this PHP file in every minute.

I could also used the command line, because there aren't time limit, but I didn't have SSH access.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for PHP to dynamically create this whenever it's needed (i.e. when a user attempts to access a post on the old table, PHP will detect it and automatically process it to the new location), this way you only do the ones you need, and you only need to do them once each. You also divide the work over a longer period of time, which will save you some server load.

This method is not recommended if you have a multitude of users and/or high traffic.